# SharePoint 2010 or 2013 on prem - offline access

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, document-library, offline-sync

Can't find any articles that has instructions on how to setup library for offline access.

We have several location out in the jungle and they have very limited connectivity via satellite.

Is there a way to make the libraries offline for this locations? If yes, how do I do that?

We are using both SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013. (I looked at OneDrive but it looks like it only works for SP online).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SharePoint Server **2010**, use **[SharePoint Workspace 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/basic-tasks-in-sharepoint-workspace-2010-77d8016f-f508-440f-bba6-a590f2527d38)** which supports offline sync with documents. Product Guide [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/2/26253c22-d8ec-4230-a3ed-e2deed9e8ebe/microsoft%20sharepoint%20workspace%202010%20product%20guide_final.pdf).

For SharePoint Server **2013**, use the [**previous OneDrive for Business sync app (Groove.exe)**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/install-previous-sync-app#install-grooveexe-with-office-2013) to sync files on local drive.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking in to OneDrive for Business, specifically the old Groove.exe version which is used with SharePoint 2013 to sync libraries with user machines so that files can be accessed offline. Unfortunately, it doesn't support SharePoint 2010. More information can be found here:

[Sync SharePoint files with the OneDrive sync client (Groove.exe)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-with-the-onedrive-sync-client-groove-exe-59b1de2b-519e-4d3a-8f45-51647cf291cd)